# Is there a way to add elevation or shadow to the thumb and track of a Slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-slider

I am working on a Slider in flutter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDkej.png), I am copying the design in the picture, but I can't add an elevation or shadow to the thumb and track of the slider. Please have a look if you guys can help.

PS: incase the link doesn't open this is an alternate link:

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/4320847/screenshots/11368106/media/85457218feaf4bd4db424331de66d097.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cupertino Slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSlider-class.html) is visually closer to what you want, but you're exploring a design language that Flutter does not have built-in widgets for.

Flutter supports the Apple design language with `Cupertino` widgets, and Material Design with `Material` widgets.

You are using a trendy design language called neumorphism. [Some of the work has been done for you already.](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic)